# AVMakeRect returning working value when I use constraints

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, avfoundation, cgrect

I am using AVMakeRect to get the image coordinates this is my code for that .

```
let x: CGRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: pointsView.imageView.frame)
```

This is output:

```
(50.9430284857571, 40.0, 272.113943028486, 484.0)
```

This is my constraints set up:
[image]

This is the image I used to get the output :
[image]

You can see there is no space on top of the image view but it is sending me the y value as 40 and x value as 50 .

What was wrong with my constraints and code ?

Comment: Try this, you are using navigation. override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    }

Comment: Try isTranslucent = false or True

Comment: @iOS tried but still same response .

Comment: this is uiview custom one , so I am placing it on full screen , there is no navigation on top .

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Add top constraint outlet and in override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() topConstraint.constant = 50 } In recent Swift we need to change cinstriants in viewDidLayoutSubviews sometimes.

Comment: Hay try this  func viewDidLayoutSubviews() { super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() topConstraint.constant = 50 }

Comment: @iOS the top constraints was fine , but the av method returning wrong aspect ration

Comment: Nice very good, now resize complete imageView frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: If required change the complete frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews based on your requirements..

Comment: @iOS can you post it as better explanation in answer phase , so that it will be helpful for some one , I will accept it ,It was a frame updation issue .

Comment: Is your problem solved with this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you uses auto layout you need to change the constraints in viewDidLayoutSubviews based on our requirements.

Add top constraint outlet.

```
func viewDidLayoutSubviews() { 
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() 
    topConstraint.constant = 50 
}
```

Comment: From your point I understood the view frame is updating on screen , but while printing I saw the dimension was wrong , later I updated frame on view did sub layout.